# Itext not supporting bookmarks in pdf

Tags: itext, html-to-pdf

iText5 does not support inline bookmark href when pdf is generated from HTML 
content. However, it is working for external links.

Is there any way we can handle inline links to other pages in the same pdf while generating pdf from HTML content?

```
<a href='#last'>Last div content</a>   <!--Not working in pdf-->
<br />
<a href='https://www.google.com'>External link</a>   <!--working in pdf-->
<br />  

<div id="last">last content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

iText 5 XMLWorker is clearly marked as deprecated on [their product page](https://itextpdf.com/en/products).

The best alternative would be to switch to iText7 + [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfhtml)

```
public void createPdf(String html, String dest) throws IOException {
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(html, new FileOutputStream(dest));
}
```